# Android GridView: two colulmns of equal width and height centred in the parent

Tags: android-layout

How can such a simple requirement be so impossible?

```
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:weightSum="3">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="6dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <GridLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:paddingTop="18dp"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:paddingLeft="12dp"
                android:background="@drawable/box_background"
                android:columnCount="2"
                >
                <TextView
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:padding="4dp"
                    android:text="text"
                    android:textSize="24dp"
                    />
                <TextView
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:padding="4dp"
                    android:text="text"
                    android:textSize="24dp"
                    />
                <TextView
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:padding="4dp"
                    android:text="text"
                    android:textSize="24dp"
                    />
                <TextView
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:padding="4dp"
                    android:text="text"
                    android:textSize="24dp"
                    />
                <TextView
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:padding="4dp"
                    android:text="text"
                    android:textSize="24dp"
                    />
                <TextView
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:padding="4dp"
                    android:text="text"
                    android:textSize="24dp"
                    />

            </GridLayout>

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:background="#fff"
                android:paddingLeft="6dp"
                android:paddingRight="6dp"
                android:text="Box title" />
        </RelativeLayout>

    </LinearLayout>
```

Produces this rubbish:

[image]

WTF is the gap above the third row?

Is it possible -- I swear it isn't -- to get two centred columns with the rows evenly spaced?

Comment: post the grid_item.xml that you are using to populate the grid view ...

Comment: My original post contains the XML.

Comment: Got it ...did't noticed it my bad...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this add   `android:layout_columnWeight="1"` to gridlayout childrens

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:weightSum="3">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="6dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <GridLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/grid_layout"
                android:columnCount="2"
                android:layout_below="@id/title"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:useDefaultMargins="true"
                android:alignmentMode="alignBounds"
                >

                <TextView
                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:padding="4dp"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:text="text"
                   android:layout_columnWeight="1"
                    android:textSize="20sp"
                    />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:padding="4dp"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:text="text"
                    android:layout_columnWeight="1"
                    android:textSize="20sp"
                    />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:padding="4dp"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:text="text"
                    android:layout_columnWeight="1"
                    android:textSize="20sp"
                    />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:padding="4dp"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:text="text"
                    android:layout_columnWeight="1"
                    android:textSize="20sp"
                    />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:padding="4dp"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:text="text"
                    android:layout_columnWeight="1"
                    android:textSize="20sp"
                    />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:padding="4dp"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:text="text"
                    android:layout_columnWeight="1"
                    android:textSize="20sp"
                    />

            </GridLayout>

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:background="#fff"
                android:paddingLeft="6dp"
                android:id="@+id/title"
                android:textSize="16sp"
                android:paddingRight="6dp"
                android:text="Box title" />

        </RelativeLayout>

    </LinearLayout>



</LinearLayout>
```

Output :

[image]

Comment: @RichardBarraclough  haven't went to depth  ... I was confused you were using GridView that's why I asked for layout view item XML. But for me also it still does't make any sense

Comment: I'm using `GridView` because I need a tabular layout -- with aligning rows and columns. Is that not how it's done?

Comment: @RichardBarraclough No it's totally fine ... you are supposed to do it like that only...